# OpenGL drawing models in incorrect order

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

I am trying to make a Cocoa application that renders a room with some models in it.

For the model importing i used [JEFF LAMARCHE's WavefrontOBJScene class](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/another-wavefront-obj-loader.html) which I modified
to work with OSX instead of iOS.

The problem is, when I try to render the models they don't render correctly.
I can't find an explanation as to why this happens.

[EXAMPLE IMAGES][image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4556129/untitled%20folder%202/Untitled.jpg]

As you can see the Pyramid's inside faces are visible, and even though the Cube is behind the Pyramid it appears to be infront.

Drawing code

```
- (BOOL) initGL
{
    test = !test;
    //glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    //glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );                // Enable texture mapping
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );                // Enable smooth shading
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f );   // Black background
    glClearDepth( 1.0f );                     // Depth buffer setup
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );                // Enable depth testing
    glDepthFunc( GL_LEQUAL );                 // Type of depth test to do
    glDepthRange(0,1);

    // Really nice perspective calculations
    glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST );
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);


    return !test;
}
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    if (!test) [self initGL];

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self setCamera];
    [self drawObjects];

    glFlush();
}

- (void)drawObjects
{
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix();
    [self drawAnObject];
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    [[objects objectAtIndex:0] openGLDraw];
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    [[objects objectAtIndex:1] openGLDraw];
    glPopMatrix();

}

- (void)drawAnObject
{    
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        for (int x = -256; x < 256; ++x) {
            for (int y = -256; y < 256; ++y) {
                glColor3f(colorR[256+x][256+y], colorG[256+x][256+y], colorB[256+x][256+y]);

                //glNormal3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

                glVertex3f( x    , -1.0, y);
                glVertex3f( x+1.0, -1.0, y);
                glVertex3f( x+1.0, -1.0, y+1.0);
                glVertex3f( x    , -1.0, y+1.0);
            }
        }
    }
    glEnd();

    //glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    //glLoadIdentity();
}


- (void)setCamera
{    
    //SET
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 60, (float)(self.frame.size.width/self.frame.size.height), 0.1, 1000.0 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef( -cameraRotationY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); //ROT Y
    glRotatef( cameraRotationX, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ); //ROT X
    glTranslatef( -cameraPositionX, -cameraPositionY, cameraPositionZ ); // POS X Y Z
}
```

CSObject:

```
- (void)openGLDraw
{       
    glPushMatrix();
    //glLoadIdentity();


    //Set Origin
    glTranslatef( posX, posY, -posZ ); // POS X Y Z
    glRotatef( rotV, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); //ROT Y
    glRotatef( rotH, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ); //ROT X

    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    //Draw objects
    for(CSGroup *group in groups) {        
        if(TRUE) {
            glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        } else {
            glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
        }

        //VERTICES
        GLuint verticesName = [group verticesName:GL_STATIC_DRAW];
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesName);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        //NORMALS
        GLuint normalsName = [group normalsName:GL_STATIC_DRAW];
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalsName);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        ColorRGBA color = group.material.ambientColor;
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, (GLfloat *)&color);
        color = group.material.diffuseColor;
        glColor4f(color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, (GLfloat *)&color);
        color = group.material.specularColor;
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, (GLfloat *)&color);
        glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, group.material.shine);

        // load (if necessary) and bind the texture
        if(group.textureCoordinatesIndexData.length > 0) {
            glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            GLuint textureCoordsName = [group textureCoordinatesName:GL_STATIC_DRAW];
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordsName);
            glTexCoordPointer([group texCoordSize], GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
            GLuint texId = [group.material.diffuseTexture textureName];
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
        }

        GLuint indexesName = [group indexesName:GL_STATIC_DRAW];
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexesName);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)group.indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);

        if(group.textureCoordinatesIndexData.length > 0) {
            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        }
    }

    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Can you check the value of `GL_DEPTH_BITS` with `glGet`? It looks to me like your context has no depth buffer.

Comment: @Tim I did as you said and added the following lines in GLinit and drawRect (before and after glClear): 

`glGetIntegerv(GL_DEPTH_BITS, &testDepth);
NSLog(@"BEFORE CLEAR: %d",testDepth);`

They all return 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that your DEPTH_BITS is returning zero means that you have no depth buffer. Therefore depth test will always pass, and you won't be able to sort things by depth.

I'm not too familiar with Cocoa, but basically what you have to do is at the time when you create your opengl context, you must request a depth buffer to be created as well. (this would be around the time when you request the number of color bits).

I don't know exactly what command controls this for cocoa, but you may be able to find it here if you don't know ([developer.apple.com - opengl_pixelformats](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_pixelformats/opengl_pixelformats.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH214-SW9)). Pay attention to any mention of depth here, and make sure you request a depth buffer.

Comment: Just to simplify things for future readers. You cen set the DepthBuffer in InterfaceBuilder when you click on your OpenGLView.